# How can I find the indexes of an element in Haskell list

Tags: list, haskell

Here is a Haskell list:

```
[[1],[3,5],[],[1,9],[3,5],[9,7],[1,9]]
```

I want to find the exact index of its elements. I tried to use `elemIndex` but it doesn't give the correct index when I try to find duplicated element like `[3,5]` and `[1,9]`.

Comment: when you look for a duplicated element, do you want the first index, the last index, or all indices?

Comment: Do you mean you want to find _all_ the locations of `[3,5]` - not jus the first?

Comment: Yes! all locations. For example for [3,5] the index will be [1,4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
> elemIndices  [3,5] [[1],[3,5],[],[1,9],[3,5],[9,7],[1,9]]
[1,4]
```

Comment: How about if I want to associate it with it's index like [(0,[1]), (1,[3,5]), (2,[]), (3,[1,9]), (4,[3,5]), (5,[9,7]), (6,[1,9])]