# How to associate elements with their indexes in haskell list

Tags: haskell

Given a list `[[1],[3,5],[],[1,9],[3,5],[9,7],[1,9]]`, how can I associate it with element indexes like `[(0,[1]), (1,[3,5]), (2,[]), (3,[1,9]), (4,[3,5]), (5,[9,7]), (6,[1,9])]`

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514828/how-can-i-find-the-index-of-an-element-in-haskell-list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use zip

```
zip [0..] theList
```

For example

```
zip [0..] [[1],[3,5],[],[1,9],[3,5],[9,7],[1,9]]
```

yields

```
[(0,[1]), (1,[3,5]), (2,[]), (3,[1,9]), (4,[3,5]), (5,[9,7]), (6,[1,9])]
```